# Checking of whether email exist or not, only works for gmail accounts, others not working

Tags: python, email-validation

I am creating a python function to check whether a given email ID really exists or not in Python. Here is my code:

```
def email_validate(email_address):
    addressToVerify = email_address
    domain_name = addressToVerify.split('@')[1]
    try:
        records = dns.resolver.query(domain_name, 'MX')
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        a = traceback.format_exc()
        print a
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success":False,"message":"Email Domain is not valid."}), content_type="application/json")

    mxRecord = records[0].exchange
    mxRecord = str(mxRecord)

    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.set_debuglevel(0)

    # SMTP Conversation
    server.connect(mxRecord)
    server.helo(host)
    server.mail('me@domain.com')
    try:
        code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
        server.quit()
    except:
        a = traceback.format_exc()

    if code == 250:
         return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success":True,"message":"Email ID is valid."}), content_type="application/json")
    else:
         return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success":False,"message":"Email ID is not valid."}), content_type="application/json")
```

This code works fine for Gmail accounts, but it gives an error for other email ID's. If I try other Email ID's, this line:

```
code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
```

gives an error...
Also, how should I check this for other email ID's?

Comment: have you tried just a separate program with several different hand-coded inputs into `server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))` to verify that it is working? Also, what is the error precisely? You have it in a `try` block so you should be handling the exception...

Comment: you can try using [validate_email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email) package!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Nurzhan Its is giving error as follows SMTPServerDisconnected('Connection unexpectedly closed',)

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran. I tried this validate_email package, but is not working properly. It is returning None Value

Comment: @AKHILMATHEW What email domains are you trying to validate?

Comment: Did you try this?  validate_email(mail_id , check_mx = True) 
here mail_id is a string .You need pydns package too for this purpose!

Comment: @ShawnMehan.. I am getting error like this..SMTPServerDisconnected('Connection unexpectedly closed',). But for Gmail ID's all conditions are working

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran.. I tried validate_email(mail_id , check_mx = True). Always it returns True. And validate_email(mail_id , verify = True) returns None always..

Comment: @Nurzhan.. I am trying to validate most of the common emails domains like  Gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc

Comment: >>> validate_email.validate_email('keerthi.pkrn@gl.com',verify=True)
>>> validate_email.validate_email('keerthi.pkrn@gmail.com',verify=True)
True
>>> validate_email.validate_email('kegre@gmail.com',verify=True)
>>>


It is working as expected. Can you please share a sample mail id you you get error response.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran.. The same only i tried. Its working for gmail accounts. But it is giving None for other emails like hotmail

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran. If you check yahoo email id it will give True for whatever email you give

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do a variation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_verification have you read through this Wiki (including the warnings about why it doesn't always work)?

Comment: Is there any problem with my question, as everyone is down voting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An RCPT command is never a good idea to check for email validation, most SMTP servers will ban your IP after several attempts or ignore you command to keep their emails safe from spammers.
The only way to validate an email existance is to send a validation email.

Comment: I am implementing this kind of check, because most of my mails are bouncing and this may affect my reputation. So before sending the email i need to verify it..

Comment: In this case, you should contact the SMTP server admins and ask for permission, one other thing you can try, is trying to create the same email for the same domain(yahoo, google ...) using browser automation and see if the username is taken, but the only reliable method is to send a confirmation link or token

Comment: I will be having bulk of emails. I can't send and confirm

Comment: Even if all SMTP servers respond to your RCPT request, that only proves the email exists, it does not help validating the user account,since you can't tell if that email belongs to a particular user, any user can use any existing email and starts creating accounts, you should consider this scenario

Comment: For that purpose only I am checking whether Email Box(End User) is existing or not and I am able to validate only Gmail Id's

Comment: @AKHILMATHEW let me know if you ever get this to work; I could make a retirement out of selling that technique to spammers. Or put more constructively: you can't have what you want because the vast majority of email servers have turned off support due to spam. I'm surprised it even works for GMail, I guess they are so confident in their other spam prevention methods that there is a net benefit to leaving this enabled.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , i have been doing web scraping and automation for years, many clients want something that involves email validation, there is just no reliable way to do it

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Yes it is working for Gmail accounts

Comment: I wouldn't use language so strong as "...RCPT command is never a good idea...", as it is a standard feature of popular MTAs, although the feature comes with warning labels. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_verification

Comment: It is a standard feature that is DISABLED by most MTAs to protect directory harvest attacks, from a practical point of view, RCPT command is most of the time useless.

Comment: @MartijnPieters (+ SEDaradji) this technique no longer works for Gmail, as far as I can see.... however, do you think this would qualify for a bug bounty reward from google if someone figures out how to validate if a gmail exists, without having to send out an actual email received by the rcpt if it does indeed exist? https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/reward-program/

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check emails in your google domain for G Suite you can use these:

1) First you need to get the right credentials to be able to access data for the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly --
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

2) Second you can use the service object created with these credentials to check if the email exists: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python